# Videos never load on facebook, Lubuntu 14.04 LTS, Firefox

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, video, facebook

I'm having a small problem with my computer. (Luckily I'm not a huge FB user or else I'd probably be loosing my crap lol.) My machine is an HP Pavilion dv4.

I can't seem to get videos to play on Facebook. I thought it was a connection-based issue (tethering 3g) but then I got home on my WI-FI and it still didn't work.

The problem in detail: When I'm on Facebook (let's say, for example, my mom's page) (lol) and I click a video, the popup window-looking thing ("enlarged view with comments on the right") that comes up for photos comes up, with the black on the left and the three vertical loading bars that... well, load, move, animate, whatever. However, the video never actually plays. I've seen this happen on videos as short as 3 second long (or was it 7 seconds...?). Also, the videos do NOT auto-play.

However, some videos (embedded, maybe?) still work when clicked on. These videos don't open, they just play. Basically if it doesn't open in the enlarged view thing with the comments on the right, then it played, but if that comment thing opens, it never loads.

I've got no clue what could be causing this; I've got flash enabled and working on other websites. If it's any help, the youtube HTML5 player is laggy on my machine, and the flash version works perfectly fine. Also I'm running Lubuntu because my machine can't properly support the Unity desktop environment, most likely due to the amd/ati config it has going on in the hardware department.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not use Facebook so I am not sure but I guess it is because of the lack of H.264 codec support on Firefox.

Try to install the FFmpeg plugin for GStreamer :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems to have fixed the problem I had with Facebook! Though now the videos that used to "open up" with the comments next to them no longer do that, but i can watch them now so I'm happy! :)

Comment: You might also check/try this plug-in - OpenH264 Video Codec provided by Cisco Systems, Inc. You don't say what FF version you are using, but recent versions should have this installed by default.